# How do I sign out of Google, Yahoo, or LiveID with ACS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, acs

I am signing out from the FAM correctly, but my cookies are still being stored in a way that doesn't prompt them for credentials after the SignIn link is checked.

I think the issue is with a cookie being saved from Yahoo or gmail. How do I erase it?

Or if I describe the situation another way..I havemore than one user needs to use my application on the same computer.  They both log in one at a time. They both have gmail or yahoo IDs.  How do I sign out correctly so that the other person can sign in?  As it stands now, only one gmail user can use the system until they erase all cookies in the machine... which isn't a viable solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After the wsignout1.0 (a request to a requestor IP/STS to delete the cached session state for a specific user) do you send a wsignoutcleanup1.0 (a request to a relying party to delete the cached session state for a specific user)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I have sent a wsignoutcleanup1.0 to relying party to delete the cached session for user, how ever the information of Google/Yahoo is still keeping and when we click on Login link, it doesn't prompt for credentials (Username/Password) and go straight to Home page. And we can only use other Google/Yahoo account when we have to go to Google/Yahoo page and sign out them.